# Does Dart have an equivalent to Python's Pickle to serialize collections of objects?

Tags: dart

I want to store data from my Dart application in a file.

I'm looking for simplest reliable way to serialize my data into something to save and reload.

Comment: You can serialize methods such as JSON to store the data per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181084/dart-writing-an-object-to-binaryfile  Article on using Dart convert package for this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47